# secure password when mounting the file server using .smbcredentials

Tags: server, mount, ssh, password, cifs

does anyone know a method that I can secure my .smbcredentials when I auto-mount my file server or even prompt for password when it auto-mount the file server as soon as I log-in?

also does the same as I SSh onto my Ubuntu computer?

I'm a beginner level in Ubuntu.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't use `.smbcredentials` to begin with and try adding `sudo mount fileshare` to your startup applications

Comment: thanks. I tried the command line in terminal, I got an error message that mount point does not exist and I also tried putting that command line in etc/fstab and it couldn't mount. I was able to put "#password=" in the .smbcredentials to prompt for password when I mount it using the terminal. Still no luck on prompt for password & username when trying to auto-mount at login for standard user and admin.

Comment: What was the exact command that you used in the terminal?  please [edit] your question to provide more details.  Don't put it in the comments, please.  **;-)**

Comment: many thank you, Fabby. My senior tech was able to resolve the issue. it was adding "noauto" and mounting it on the home folder instead of the media folder.

Comment: I also added "#password=" on the .smbcredentials

Answer (score 3):

This is the way I secure the .smbcredentials:

I have a (veracrypt-)encrypted SD Card in my PC. I save the .smbcredentials file on this SD Card, so nobody can snoop it out using a Live-CD. 
In my case, the encrypted SD Card is automatically mounted after boot using a veracrypt-keyfile, this is to circumvent manual authentication i.e. for convenience.

For the automount I use a simple script with the content along the lines of:

```
veracrypt -k /home/user/Documents/KeePass/SD128.keyfile -p "" /dev/mmcblk0p2
```

*/dev/mmcblk0p2* is the Device ID of the SD Card.
The script can then be placed in 'Startup Applications'.

This way, there is zero interaction necessary from my side as everything mounts automatically (local Disks, Network Shares and encrypted SD Card with the smbcredentials on it).

This is reasonably safe, since, if I lose my Laptop (and with it the keyfile), the average user won't figure out how he can access my encrypted data (maybe there is a better place to store the keyfile? Please enlighten me...).

However, sure thing is that it would be safer without a keyfile and with manual authentication, since whoever owns the keyfile can mount your encrypted Data. It's up to you, if you want it safer, don't use the keyfile in this way, use a password instead.

The thing is, I never remove the SD Card from my Laptop. However, if you remove it and store it at a safe place when not in use, the whole setup is rather safe.

Comment: If you store the keyfile on a second (unencrypted) removable device then you can safely leave your sd card in your pc if you keep the unencrypted device secure (keep it on you?) -- and you'll be more likely to since it's less secure. Or you can get added security by keeping the two different cards in different places.